# blackberry push notification client-side

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, client-side

I got a problem while running the client-sample-app source that i import into eclipse,
while i run this example in device, I got this error :

Class 'com.rim.samples.device.push.Logger$LogMessages' multiply defined.
Error starting Push: Class 'com.rim.samples.device.push.Logger$LogMessages' multiply defined.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have another sample app installed on the device, which defines the same Logger.LogMessages class.   Delete the other sample apps, and this one should start working.

Comment: I don't have any others applications just one. I resolve  the problem by renaming the class. Thanks